# DataTemplate Selector Doesn't get called

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to use a `DataTemplateSelector` to load different sets of controls based on a combobox selection but it seems to never get called. There is nothing fancy inside my DataTemplates except labels and more comboboxes inside a grid.

Here is my TemplateSelector

```
public class PWRPTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{

    public DataTemplate Product { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Project { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if(item == null) { return base.SelectTemplate(item, container); }
        return (int)item == 0 ? Product : Project;

    }
}
```

And my xaml

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="Project">
  .....
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="Project">
  .....
  </DataTemplate>

    <c:PWRPTemplateSelector x:Key="PWRPTemplateSelector" Product="{StaticResource Product}" Project="{StaticResource Project}"/>



   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TestSelc,  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource PWRPTemplateSelector}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

My ItemControl is bound to the selected property of a Combobox which is an `int`. Everything gets executed properly, except the DataTemplate never gets called. All of the property's get change and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

UPDATE:

I can get my `DataTemplateSelector` if I change my selected item to a `string` value. However, the value gets passed as a `char` and not the entire string. The method gets called for every char in the string then.

Comment: Is the DataTemplateSelector your real code? Because it will not even compile because of comparing `int` to `object`

Comment: No, sorry about that, forgot my cast to int.

Comment: The `ItemsSource` property is an `IEnumerable`, so when you bind it to a string, it uses the string as `IEnumerable` i.e. a collection of `char` items.

Comment: @Clemens that makes sense. But why doesn't it get called at all when I have an integer?

Comment: Because an `int` is not an `IEnumerable`. You should see a binding error message in the Output Window in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Clemens thank you! I changed to a content control and am able to bind on an integer and get the correct results.